# can we generate hmac in SSJS Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to find SSJS function in marketing cloud.
is there any way to generate hmac sha256 in server side javascript in marketing cloud ? does SSJS has any equivalent to CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(, ) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This question was previously answered in [this StackExchange thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233954/is-it-possible-to-perform-hmac-sha1-encoding-with-ampscript), but to summarize, AMPScript provides the SHA256() hashing function, but neither SSJS nor AMPScript support HMAC.