# How to generate HMAC SHA-256

Tags: marketing-cloud, hashcode

I have gone through these,

1. [can we generate hmac in SSJS Marketing cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307542/can-we-generate-hmac-in-ssjs-marketing-cloud)
2. [Is it possible to perform HMAC SHA1 encoding with Ampscript?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233954/is-it-possible-to-perform-hmac-sha1-encoding-with-ampscript)

But check again as a new question, if there is any latest update on this.
Any alternate/custom solution to achieve this?

I did try this,

```html
%%[ SET @plainToken = "TestToken"]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output"><div>  

<script>var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("%%=v(@plainToken)=%%", "TestSecrete");
var hashInBase64 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = hashInBase64;

</script>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

But I wanted to generate a JSON out of this generated Hash.
Basically, I am trying to authenticate my CodeResource URL, to a [Zoom WEBHOOK](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/webhook-reference/#validate-your-webhook-endpoint) as mentioned here.

Any suggestion/guiding in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Down voting :D
Which made me to find this solution here

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sfmc-ninja?trackingId=nvCZNjYVTFOFWRq%2BmA4PSA%3D%3D&lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_detail_base%3BezDRI53AQ928jhqNoFuU%2Bw%3D%3D